# Excel VBA: Changin concatenate, mid and find formulas to VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I am creating another VBA for that i need value from excel formula to VBA...

> excel formula is
>
> > =CONCATENATE(MID(J11,1,FIND("_",J11,1)),"#.jpg")
>
> the code i record in VBA using excel macro is...
>
> > ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
> >
> > "=CONCATENATE(MID(RC[-1],1,FIND(""_"",RC[-1],1)),""#.jpg"")"
>
> this give value in Activecell of excel but i need value in a variable of VBA.

Comment: you don't need excel formula here, all you need is VBA concatenation with `&` and VBA functions like `Mid()`, `InStr()` plus references to a Range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code in vba -

```
Dim str As String

str = Mid(Sheets("sheetname").Range("J11").Value, 1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("_", Sheets("sheetname").Range("J11").Value, 1)) & "#.jpg"
```

Just change the sheetname as per your sheets.